# How to get the ram footprint of a specific object in JRuby

Tags: jruby

Is there a way to query the ram footprint of a specific object in JRuby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you heard about [jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html), [jhat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html), and [visualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/)?

1. jmap outputs the object memory maps / heap memory details for the given Java process.
2. jhat is a heap analysis tool that lets you create a Java heap dump, and then lets you query it using a SQL-like language to get more detail.
3. visualvm is yet another Java tool for viewing details about a Java applications as they are running in the JVM.

I found [this post from Charles Nutter](http://blog.headius.com/2010/07/browsing-memory-jruby-way.html) to be very helpful in getting me started in JRuby profiling and memory inspection.